# Different git submodules pointing to different tags/branches from same repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

The scene is I have a git project A and it has a submodule pointing to project B repo, i.e. to a specific tag from such repo. I would like to create a branch in A that could point to a different tag from B.
Questions: Is it possible? If yes, how? If no, I would like listen to your suggestions about a better project structure to allow this.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Without to have cloning repo B again.

Comment: Are you looking to simultaneously checkout submodule B's tag 1, and tag 2?  If so, no, that is cray-cray.  :)

Comment: No. I'm with two different branchs: A and A'. Initially A depends submodule B. But as I create other branch, A', I want it passes to depend submodule B', an updated revision of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes! This is definitely possible, but first a little clarification.

**How git stores references to submodules**

A git submodule (project B in your example) is always referenced by the main git project (A) by specifying a **commit** (its SHA-1 hash).
The commit you are pointing to may also correspond to a tag (or a branch head), just remember that git stores the referenced hash. So, if you (for any reason) delete your tag in project B or even move it, project A will keep on referencing the initial commit.

**Create a branch in the main project that points to a different commit in the submodule**

Let's assume this: project A in its main branch (`master`) is referencing project B at a certain tag (`tagB1`). So you have already linked it as a submodule and it is stored into `projB` folder

1. Create your branch in project A and switch to it as you would usually do.

   > `git checkout -b NewBranch`
2. Change to your submodule (`projB`) directory

   > `cd projB`
3. Switch (checkout) your submodule to the new commit or tag as desired

   > `git checkout tagB2`
4. Go back to project A main folder and commit it. This stores the link between project A (in the branch `NewBranch`) to the tag you have selected (actually the **hash of the commit** is stored, as explained)

**Switching between main project branches and submodules**

This is important to remember: if you switch your main project branch , the submodules will not automatically follow the main branch!!
In our example, if you switch project A back to `master` branch, project B will remain to the version `tagB2` and not `tagB1` as you may think..

You need to run the command `git submodule update`

For more information check the [ProGit chapter about submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)